# How to find a model using a nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

I have a User Model that has nested attributes.

One of these nested attributes is email.

Is it possible to find a user model by using the email address that is found in the nested attributes?

So something similar to `User.find_by(email: "email@example.com")` but looks at the nested email attribute instead of directly at the top level user model.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that **User has_many :emails** and **Email table has address column**

you can use `includes` to do what you want

```
User.includes(:emails).where(emails: { address: 'boris@test.com' })
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if you have email as a nested attribute it implies a has_one or has_many relationship from user to email

The reverse of that is belongs_to. E.g.

```
belongs_to :user
```

In your email class. With that in place, you can simply do:

```
Email.find_by(email: 'boris@test.com').user
```